# Highcharts（複数グラフでのツールチップ表示）

Tags: highcharts

例えば、前年と今年の様にx軸の同一目盛り上に複数グラフを表示した際、１つのツールチップに複数のグラフの値を表示する方法を教えて下さい。グラフにカーソルをあてると１つの値が表示されるケースと複数の値が表示されるケースがあり不定です。

現在のツールチップ設定内容

```
       tooltip: {
           crosshairs: true
          ,shared: true
          ,pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}:</span> {point.y}<br>'
       }
```

Comment: 「グラフにカーソルをあてると１つの値が表示されるケースと複数の値が表示されるケースがあり不定です。」の意味がよく分かりませんでした。もう少し具体的な説明をしてもらえませんか。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
不定の意味は、１つのｘ軸に複数のグラフを描いた場合、カーソルとあてると本来複数分の値が常に出てほしいところ、何故か１つの値が出たり、正しく複数の値がするという意味です。複数のグラフとは、例えばｘ軸：４月に前年と今年の実績棒グラフを表示している状態です。

Comment: コメントではなく、質問を編集してください。Bar Chartですね。具体的にとは、実際のコードを提示してもらえると良いです。

Comment: 再現しようとしましたが、tooltipの情報だけでは厳しいようです。可能な範囲でグラフのコードを提示できませんか。http://jsfiddle.net/fx6r7wmd/1/

Answer (score 1):

`tooltip.shared = true` を試してみて下さい。

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.shared

[bar-basic](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-basic)のデモに適用すると以下のようになります。

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Historic World Population by Region'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_population">Wikipedia.org</a>'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'],
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Population (millions)',
                align: 'high'
            },
            labels: {
                overflow: 'justify'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' millions',
            shared: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -40,
            y: 80,
            floating: true,
            borderWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
            shadow: true
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Year 1800',
            data: [107, 31, 635, 203, 2]
        }, {
            name: 'Year 1900',
            data: [133, 156, 947, 408, 6]
        }, {
            name: 'Year 2012',
            data: [1052, 954, 4250, 740, 38]
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```